What is pipe-digit-dash in YAML?
I've just started working with ruamel.yaml in Python, and I compose a dict dynamically, some of whose keys contain multiline strings generated as per Can I control the formatting of multiline strings? ; and I've noticed, sometimes the output is as expected:
      - mystring: |-
          Here line 1 of my string;
          Here another line 2 of my string

... but sometimes I get output like this:
      - mystring: |2-
           (comment) here line 1;
          "and" here line 2 of my string

As per https://yaml-multiline.info/, I understand that in pipe-dash |-, the pipe is "Block Style Indicator", and the dash is "Block Chomping Indicator" - but I do not understand what the digit should be for in pipe-digit-dash, say |2-?
The https://yaml-multiline.info/ has an interactive applet that allows you to set "Include indentation indicator", but in that case, with "Block Scalar Style: Keep newlines (literal)" and "Block Chomping: No newline at end (strip)", you get |-2, that is pipe-dash-digit - not pipe-digit-dash.
So what would pipe-digit-dash |2- mean in YAML?

It can be -2 or 2-, per e.g. https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#block-scalar-styles

Ah thanks @jonrsharpe, I did not catch that

Normally the indent of block style literal scalar, is determined by its first line, i.e. how much it is indented relative to the line on which the |- appears. Once the YAML parser find a line that is less indented, it assumes that the literal scalar has ended on the line before that. The amount of indentation, on dumping is normally 2, but during parsing this is scanned from the first non-blank line of the literal style scalar.
However if during dumping the string represented as a literal style scalar starts with a space, then the first line will have an extra indent, and the second line would trigger end-of-literal-scalar, because it dedents. In that case the dump routine explicitly indicates how many characters of indent level should be assumed, in your case |2-, so to character indent. Your Python string therefor probably looked like " (comment) here line 1;\n          "and" here line 2 of my string" (note the leading space).
